# Crear instalador de aplicación con base de datos en Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Buen dia,

Acabo de terminar mi aplicación que estaba desarrollando en C# dentro de Visual Studio, la cual esta conectada a una base de datos del cual toma datos para consultar, registros, etc.

Mi pregunta es:

¿Como puedo crear el instalador y que ya vaya la base de datos dentro de la aplicación para así instalarla en cualquier computadora que no tenga SQL server y después poder descargar esa base de datos para manipularla en otra PC que si tenga SQL Server o vía Remota?

Yo uso el complemento de Visual Studio para crear las aplicaciones:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mas nunca había integrado una base datos.

Saludos y muchas gracias, espero haberme explicado de la mejor manera.

Comment: Para empezar, el usuario deberia instalarse un sql server. Despues, no podes pasarle el archivo de DB, si no que tenes que correr los scripts de creacion de la db.

Comment: Si tu aplicación utiliza una base de datos de SQL si requieres que exista una instancia, lo que puedes hacer por medio del instalador es solicitar la instancia de la base, el usuario el password para que puedas conectarte y crear la base por medio de los Scripts

Comment: @M.Gress buena tarde, ¿tienes alguna guia o pagina de como realizar ese procesos saludos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba esta opción:

Click derecho sobre el proyecto de instalación, esto despliega la siguiente ventana:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora dale al botón de "prerequisitos" y aparecerá una lista de posibles prerequisitos con múltiples opciones de descarga, entre estos aparece sql server.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero le sirva.